# Java 8 streams maintain specific map key order return from group by operation

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list with collections of TitleIsbnBean objects. I wrote the following code snippet to group by this collection by learning area type as below.

```
titleListByLearningArea = nonPackageIsbnList.stream()
      .collect(groupingBy(TitleIsbnBean::getKeylearningarea,
                          LinkedHashMap::new,Collectors.toList())

              );
```

but I want to preserve the following specific order in the map return from the above stream.

```
titleListByLearningArea.put("Commerce", new ArrayList<TitleIsbnBean>() {});
titleListByLearningArea.put("English", new ArrayList<TitleIsbnBean>() {});
titleListByLearningArea.put("Health & PE", new ArrayList<TitleIsbnBean>() {});
titleListByLearningArea.put("Humanities", new ArrayList<TitleIsbnBean>() {});
titleListByLearningArea.put("Mathematics", new ArrayList<TitleIsbnBean>() {});
titleListByLearningArea.put("Music & the Arts", new ArrayList<TitleIsbnBean>() {});
titleListByLearningArea.put("Science", new ArrayList<TitleIsbnBean>() {});
titleListByLearningArea.put("Others", new ArrayList<TitleIsbnBean>() {});
```

but I'm getting a different order once I group by the collections using streams. How can I maintain a specific order when stream group by operation using.

```
class TitleIsbnBean {

  private String titleName;
  private String isbn;
  private int status;
  private String keylearningarea;

  public TitleIsbnBean(String titleName, String isbn, int status, String keylearningarea){
    super();
    this.titleName = titleName;
    this.isbn = isbn;
    this.status = status;
    this.setKeylearningarea(keylearningarea);
  }

}

ArrayList<TitleIsbnBean> nonPackageIsbnList = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String,List<TitleIsbnBean>> titleListByLearningArea = new LinkedHashMap<>();

titleListByLearningArea.put("Commerce", new ArrayList<TitleIsbnBean>() {});
titleListByLearningArea.put("English", new ArrayList<TitleIsbnBean>() {});
titleListByLearningArea.put("Health & PE", new ArrayList<TitleIsbnBean>() {});
titleListByLearningArea.put("Humanities", new ArrayList<TitleIsbnBean>() {});
titleListByLearningArea.put("Mathematics", new ArrayList<TitleIsbnBean>() {});
titleListByLearningArea.put("Music & the Arts", new ArrayList<TitleIsbnBean>() {});
titleListByLearningArea.put("Science", new ArrayList<TitleIsbnBean>() {});
titleListByLearningArea.put("Others", new ArrayList<TitleIsbnBean>() {});

titleListByLearningArea = nonPackageIsbnList.stream()
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(TitleIsbnBean::getKeylearningarea,
                                LinkedHashMap::new,Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: *I want to preserve the following specific order in the map return*... you mean the keys should be in the same order?

Comment: Here what is `nonPackageIsbnList` ? can you add details about it.

Comment: @Eklavya nonPackageIsbnList is a list with collections of TitleIsbnBean objects

Comment: @ Naman keys order  should be equals to Commerce,English,Health & PE ..............

Comment: In `nonPackageIsbnList` is the order  preserved, or you just fixed the order.

Comment: @Eklavya no there is no specific order.

Comment: A map does not have any specific order, period. If you want to preserve a specific order you have to use special maps such as `LinkedHashMap` (insertion order) or `TreeMap` (sorted based on Comparable or Comparator) and depending on how you use streams, you might also have to tell the stream that it should be ordered, `stream.ordered()`.

Comment: First sort the list in your specific order. Then do this group by operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering you need a desired order of keys for the `Map` you are collecting in, you can collect to a `TreeMap` with a `Comparator` based on `index` specified such as:

```
Collection<TitleIsbnBean> nonPackageIsbnList = .... //initialisation
List<String> orderedKeys = List.of("Commerce", "English", "Health & PE", "Humanities",
        "Mathematics", "Music & the Arts", "Science", "Others");

Map<String, List<TitleIsbnBean>> titleListByLearningArea = nonPackageIsbnList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(TitleIsbnBean::getKeylearningarea,
                () -> new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparingInt(orderedKeys::indexOf)),
                Collectors.toList()));
```

Answer (score 1):

First sort the list using `Comparator` with your desired order then collect the list in group.

```
List<String> orderKeys = List.of("Commerce", "English", "Health & PE", "Humanities",
        "Mathematics", "Music & the Arts", "Science", "Others");

Map<String, List<TitleIsbnBean>> titleListByLearningArea = nonPackageIsbnList.stream()
                   .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(t -> orderKeys.indexOf(t.getKeylearningarea())))
                   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(TitleIsbnBean::getKeylearningarea,LinkedHashMap::new,Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: In Comparator `Comparator.comparingInt(t -> orderKeys.indexOf(t.getKeylearningarea()))` . After sorting it preserved the new order I think